# Django query by parent id without join

Tags: python, django

Let's say I've two models
Parent and Child related by foreign key

want to query all children without making a join with the parent table

will

```
Child.objects.filter(
    parent_id=parent_id
)
```

do the trick?
notice I'm doing a single underscore instead of double, so in theory it should only look through parent_id column in child table instead of making the joins, right?

Answer (score 5):

**Yes**, this will *not* make a `JOIN`, but the Django query engine is smart enough that:

```
Child.objects.filter(parent__id=parent_id)
```

or:

```
Child.objects.filter(parent__pk=parent_id)
```

will *not* make a JOIN either, it will optimize that away.

You can inspect the queries Django will make with:

```
print(Child.objects.filter(parent__pk=parent_id).query)
```

that being said, even if that would make a JOIN, it would likely not make *that* much difference. The primary keys usually have an index as well as the `FOREIGN KEY`s, which have a `MUL` index. This means that it can efficiently find the corresponding record, so it will not have to do a linear search, but can use indexes, so likely the overhead would be quite small anyway.

If you however want to add the `Child` objects of multiple parents, it is *not* a good idea to make queries *per* parent, since that would introduce an *N+1 problem*. In such case it is better to use [**`.prefetch_related(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related), since that will query the parents in one query, and all the related `Child`s together in one additional query.

Comment: thanks, I was only asking because I saw in a code of some project they were avoiding to filter by parent_id to avoid the join as it'd be expensive, I was confused so I posted the question.
Again, thanks for the calrification.